# Unable to publish Azure Function v1.0 on file system as defined in publish profile using msbuild command

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, continuous-integration, azure-functions

I am trying to publish azure function v1.0 using publish profile and contents of publish profile is given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
    <Platform>Any CPU</Platform>
    <PublishDir>C:\New folder</PublishDir>
    <PublishProtocol>FileSystem</PublishProtocol>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

and this publish profile we are using with below given msbuild command (FolderProfile  is the name of publish profile that we are using within command)

```
C:\code\msbuild "mufunctionapp.csproj" /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release;PublishProfile=PublishProfiles/FolderProfile
```

But after running this command nothing gets copied(published) into the folder (**C:\New folder**) specified within publish profile. But I could see the publish artifacts ( binaries) being copied to **obj\Release\net48\PubTmp\Out\bin**

But If I use the same publish profile with Visual Studio 2019 ,the publish artifacts ( binaries) are getting copied into the folder specified within publish profile.

I want to publish the binaries using msbuild command with given publish profile within CI but as It is not working locally I am unable to use the msbuild there in CI pipeline.

Could you please tell me if there is anything that I am doing wrong in MSBUILD or in publish profile.

Comment: You can try to use ` <publishUrl>` instead of `<PublishDir>`. [related document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-5.0#folder-publish-example)

Comment: Its not working @DylanZhu-MSFT

Comment: Try to add `/p:DeployOnbuild = true`, and remove `/t:Rebuild`

Answer (score 0):

That's because of two reasons

> 1. you may have condition set to false, `Condition="false"` *buried deeply* in your `.csproject` file. Try to **delete** just that condition, and doublecheck your `$(MSBuildToolsVersion)` resolves correctly to your correct `VS 2019 build path and version` in powershell or some CLI

> 2. Now you can do the MS build, with other options but you need the two below for sure. Ref [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/command-line-deployment)

---

```
// If running build @ **Solution level
msbuild myproject.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=myVsProfile /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem 

// If running build @ individual **Project level specify the correct VS version
msbuild myproject.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=myVsProfile /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:VisualStudioVersion=17.0
```